# Fail to upload G-code with UGS Plotter Software

Tags: print-quality, g-code, diy-3d-printer, print-material, printer-building

Referring to a circle shape G-code online generator for my 2D printer at [here](https://cnc-apps.com/en/app/circle), in which I created a 100 mm circle. I downloaded the G-code from the website and try to open it with UGS plotter but it is not showing any circle in that software.

How can I solve this issue? Pardon me, I only started CNC 2 days ago and I have jogged my 2D printer I built and it works well, so now as a beginner task, I want to draw a circle.

If anyone has experience with G-code, feel free to share it with me. I appreciate it :)

[image: Screenshot of online G-code generator settings]

[image: Screenshot of UGS software with no G-code shown]

Comment: Can you share your GCODE file?

Answer (score 1):

The g-code generated by the linked site presents in a text reader as a series of G01 codes, which are strictly movement codes. As expected, the circle was created as a series of fairly short straight line segments.

There are no other g-codes of note in the created file. In the case of a 2D printer, one would expect to see a g-code for pen down/pen up, while in a 3D printer, one expects to see extrusion commands.

The first two or three g-code viewers presented zero graphic results. The last one (because, why continue?) is [NC Viewer](https://ncviewer.com/) and was able to properly display a circle. Images from linked site, using OP linked site to code 100 mm circle:

[image: G-code for 100 mm circle]

I added in a "pen-down" g-code, M3 S50 to the code and the NC Viewer site also added a pen!

[image: 100 mm circle with pen]

This would indicate that your code is good/operational/functional, but lacks additional commands to create something useful in the program on your side. Consider to examine the g-code that presents an image in your software. Research the g-codes to determine the function. For example, I did not have a pen-down g-code command memorized, but used a search engine to find "g-code pen down" nearly instantly. Directly related, the M09 g-code in the created file is one I did not recognize. A search presented the answer that it is a "coolant off" command. An unusual command to see in a generic g-code creator!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connecting to the correct port. Make sure you have installed any drivers required for your controller. Make sure GRBL is properly flashed on your controller. As a last resort try removing all previous UGS settings (see property Files) and reinstall.

Comment: I won't downvote this answer, but it's not particularly useful in this case. The posted image indicates communication is successful.